# Как привязать команду из MainViewModel к шаблонному элементу Menu в Avalonia UI?

Tags: c#, avalonia, reactive

В настоящий момент мой код в axaml таков:

```
<Menu
    Background="#1A1E27"
>

    <MenuItem
        Header="Открыть"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Projects}"
    >
        <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <MenuItem
                    Header="{Binding Path=Name}"
                >
                    <MenuItem.Styles>
                        <Style
                            Selector="MenuItem MenuItem"
                        >
                            <Setter
                                Property="Command"
                                Value="{Binding OpenProjectCommand}"
                            />
                        </Style>
                    </MenuItem.Styles> 
                </MenuItem>
            </DataTemplate>
        </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
    </MenuItem>

</Menu>
```

`Projects` - объект типа `ObservableCollection<Project>`. Приведенный axaml влечет вызов метода `OpenProjectCommand` в классе `Project`. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как я могу изменить контекст, чтобы осуществлялся вызов метода `OpenProjectCommand`, реализованного в моей `ViewModel`?

Comment: Когда вы имеете коллекцию, все объекты внутри данной коллекции получают `DataContext` на самого себя, а значит и привязки будут искаться внутри этого объекта. Чтобы привязаться к объекту выше, надо найти "предка" (Ancestor), ну а в Авалонии есть специальные для этого [ключи](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/guides/data-binding/binding-to-controls#binding-to-an-ancestor). То есть, у вас привязка должна быть примерно такой: `{Binding $parent[Window].DataContext.OpenProjectCommand}` (`Windows` (можно без него) - любой контрол за пределами коллекции, `DataContext` - свойство с заданным VM)

Answer (score 0):

Нужно использовать [атрибут `Command`](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/guides/data-binding/how-to-bind-to-a-command-with-reactiveui).

Не все элементы поддерживают этот атрибут, может потребоваться, по-хорошему, написать свой `View`, который будет поддерживать `Command`, и, по-плохому, использовать атрибут `OnClick` (вызывает метод) на месте.

Comment: Я использовал атрибут Command применительно к MenuItem. У меня тогда пункты меню стали неактивны. На github я нашел аналогичную проблему (https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/issues/3100) и сделал так, как предлагалось там (с использованием стилей).

Кроме того, указание метода в атрибуте Command влечет вызов метода класса Project, но не класса ViewModel...

Comment: Я думаю, что фреймворк разрабатывался с идеей, что команда должна легко вызываться именно у Project, и я с ним согласен. Вызвать команду у ViewModel должно быть не легко, и при нормальной архитектуре это не должно быть нужным.
Могу предложить:

1) команда в Project вызывает метод у вьюмодел
2) Project по цепочке уведомит вьюмодел, что нужно вызвать метод OpenProjectCommand

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, с помощью каких средств можно реализовать "Project [...] уведомит ViewModel, что нужно вызвать метод OpenProjectCommand"?

Comment: Я не знаю, какая у вас там архитектура в проекте. По-плохому можно добавить event в каждом Project, пройтись по Projects, подписать OpenProjectCommand на event'ы Project'ов.

Чтоб у вас получился нормальный MVVM и не страдать, надо реализовать DI полностью (коллекция сервисов) и продумать архитектуру.

Пример MVVM и DI для WPF (похоже на авалонию) https://github.com/magals/TemplateWpfMVVM

Answer (score 0):

Есил бы ты привел код как у тебя реализована команда, было бы что посмотреть, потому-что у меня на `menuitem` без проблем накидывается command. Если прям никак, то попробуй сделать через `event` вызвав эту же команду через `datacontext`

```
 var dc = DataContext as MainWindowViewModel;
 dc.AddNewRow.Execute(tb.DataContext as MarkTable).Subscribe();
```

во второй строке я через метод вызываю свою команду, внутри `Execute()` записано обращение к тексблоку через мой класс MarkTable. Также можно не писать атрибуты для `Execute`, а просто оставить его пустым

```
var dc = DataContext as MainWindowViewModel;
dc.AddNewRow.Execute().Subscribe();
```

(Хотел написать коммент, но у меня репутации мало)